# Flaky Behavior of Git --no-commit?

Tags: git

I tried a "merge --no-commit", and the --no-commit was ignored.  Why?

Here is exactly what happened:

```
baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 MINGW64 /c/repos/mobile-solutions (feature/create-new-theme)
$ git status
On branch feature/create-new-theme
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature/create-new-theme' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 MINGW64 /c/repos/mobile-solutions (feature/create-new-theme)
$ git merge --no-commit origin/feature/create-new-theme
Updating 0010daa..d835f24
Fast-forward
.../Views/CarrierAccountLines/CarrierAccountLineMenu.cshtml         | 3 +--
src/Max.Web/wwwroot/master/sass/app2/custom/all.scss                | 6 ++++++
2 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 MINGW64 /c/repos/mobile-solutions (feature/create-new-theme)
$ git status
On branch feature/create-new-theme
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/create-new-theme'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I expected no commit to be made. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

`git merge --no-commit` [won't create a **merge commit**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-commit) automatically, but this only applies if the two branches you're merging actually require a merge commit.

In this case, your branches were able to be [fast-forwarded](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), and thus no commit would have been created.

If you inspect your history `git --log --graph --oneline --pretty --decorate`, you'll observe that there's no merge commit, and the last commit(s) to your branch are identical to the one that you merged from.

If you want to prevent this from happening in the future, add `--no-ff` to the options list; this will [force Git to create a merge commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-ff) instead of no merge commit.

Comment: I'm not understanding.  Before I gave the merge command, it said that I was "1 behind" the tracking branch.  After the merge it said that my branch was "up-to-date".  How is it possible to make that transition...without creating a commit?  Said differently, did the merge command change something on my branch or did it not change something on my branch?  If it did change something...then there must be a commit, correct?  If it did not change something, then how does it now show that it is "up to date?"

Comment: I think what you (or the docs) are saying is that a fast-forward does not make a commit...precisely because the commits being "fast-fowarded" were already made.  That is, it simply appends prior-made commits.  So, an argument could be made that no "new commit" was created...even though this is a bit tongue-in-cheek because the target branch was indeed modified.  Am I correctly understanding this?

Comment: I've added a reference to the official Git docs.  From those graphics, the pointer on a branch you're merging into `master` is simply moved to match the pointer of the other branch.  I strongly encourage you to peruse the documentation until you're satisfied with how fast-forwards operate.

Comment: @BrentArias: Makoto is correct: Git did a fast-forward operation instead of creating a commit, and you can suppress the fast-forward with `--no-ff` (and then suppress the commit as well with `--no-commit` if you like: you will now be in the state where the *next* `git commit` creates the merge commit, just as you would have been had fast-forward not been possible in the first place).

Comment: I've read a lot of documentation...but I don't understand why there is not a straight answer to the question "did the `merge --no-commit` modify my branch?"  I feel like this could be answered with a "yes" or "no."